# Bootstrap4 tooltip does not work with Flask web application

Tags: flask, bootstrap-4, python-3.7

I have created Flask application with Bootstrap plugin installed. But the tooltip like presented in Bootstrap page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/ does not work.
I tried "everything" I found in Internet but stil no luck.

I am using Python3.7 and docker-compose to build the application.
The following plugins are installed:

```
Flask==1.0.3
flask-restful==0.3.7
Flask-Bootstrap4==4.0.2
flask-nav==0.6
```

In my application I am using now Flask and Flask-Bootstrap4.

I am using templates to load the child pages. My layout is like this (layout.html):

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    {% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/azcss.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    {% block navbar %}
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand">Azure</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('resource_manager') }}">Resource Manager</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    {% endblock navbar %}

        {% block content %}

        {% endblock content%}

</body>
</html>
```

In {% block content %} I am loading my home page (home.html):

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}


<div class="container-fluid">
    <p>Home</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
    
    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Title Here"> I am Here</a>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
  Tooltip on top
    </button>

<script>
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

My Flask app looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, url_for, request
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

from utils.azfunc.resource_groups_mgmt import list_all_resource_group_name, create_resource_group


app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)


@app.route('/')
def base() -> 'html':
    return render_template('layout.html')


@app.route('/home')
def home() -> 'html':
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/resource_manager')
def resource_manager() -> str:
    return render_template('resource_manager.html')


@app.route('/list_res_groups')
def list_res_grps() -> 'html':
    return render_template('list_res_groups.html', res_grps=list_all_resource_group_name())


@app.route('/create_res_group_form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_res_grp_form() -> 'html':
    return render_template('create_res_group_form.html')


@app.route('/create_res_group', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_res_grp() -> 'html':
    res_group = request.form['azgroup']
    region = request.form['azregion']
    resource_group_created = create_resource_group(res_group, region)
    return render_template('create_res_group.html', result=resource_group_created)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

Result:

The tooltip shows after 2,3 seconds but it does not look like it is Bootstrap tooltip:
[My app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb7E6.png)

According to the Bootstrap documentation it should look like this:
[Bootstrap page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRg1z.png)

The code in web browser Developer mode shows that script should work:
[Developer mode code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WfEQ.png)

**Can you please help me to get this solved?**

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by adding script in %content% section.

Thanks dylanj.nz for your hints that helped me to find the solution.

Now my layout.html looks like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    {% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/azcss.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    {% block navbar %}
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('base') }}">Azure</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('resource_manager') }}">Resource Manager</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    {% endblock navbar %}

    {% block content %}
        {% block scripts %}
            {{ super() }}
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
                })
            </script>
        
        {% endblock scripts %}
    {% endblock content %}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the default html tooltip, not the bootstrap one. It could be the ordering of your script loading, try moving your

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
</script>
```

to after/below the loading of the jquery/bootstrap scripts (I'm guessing this will be in your layout.html)

Comment: I tried putting the <script>...</script> in many locations in layout.html and it still does not work. I put this inside <head> at the beggining and at the end of <head> section. Also I put it to {% block navbar %}. When I put <script>...</script> in {% block content %} I can't see this by inspection the code.

Comment: When you call the initialisation from the dev tools console (`$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()`), does it then work? are there any console errors appearing after the page has loaded?

Comment: I put <script>...</script> in home.html and go to Code inspection -> Console and found an error: home:16 GET http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/fontawesome-all.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
home:53 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at home:53
(anonymous) @ home:53.   I am wondering why this error appear? And why it downloading bootstrap content from the bootstrap server instead of bootstrap module installed in Docker?

Answer (score 0):

@Dylanj thanks to your answers I found another way to have it working.

I think I can load css locally from Bootstrap package from location:

```
root@9949973a7f22:/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/static/css# ls -al
total 1696
drwxr-sr-x 2 root staff   4096 Jul 17 16:16 .
drwxr-sr-x 6 root staff   4096 Jul 17 16:16 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  43852 Jul 17 16:16 bootstrap-grid.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  95910 Jul 17 16:16 bootstrap-grid.css.map
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  34243 Jul 17 16:16 bootstrap-grid.min.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  76209 Jul 17 16:16 bootstrap-grid.min.css.map
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff   4798 Jul 17 16:16 bootstrap-reboot.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  57721 Jul 17 16:16 bootstrap-reboot.css.map
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff   3936 Jul 17 16:16 bootstrap-reboot.min.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  25881 Jul 17 16:16 bootstrap-reboot.min.css.map
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 178152 Jul 17 16:16 bootstrap.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 411645 Jul 17 16:16 bootstrap.css.map
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 144877 Jul 17 16:16 bootstrap.min.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 551641 Jul 17 16:16 bootstrap.min.css.map
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  35359 Jul 17 16:16 fontawesome-all.min.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  33994 Jul 17 16:16 fontawesome.min.css
```

But how to import bootstrap.min.css and fontawesome-all.min.css in layout.html?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem regarding loading bootstrap content locally by adding in Flask app the line:

```
app.config['BOOTSTRAP_SERVE_LOCAL'] = True
```

Also I've read that the script:

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
</script>
```

Should be loaded after bootstrap scripts.

Can you please tell me how to do this?